# How to show AppBarButton Label in initial load?

Tags: c#, uwp, commandbar

In the following code, the app bar is rendered without the AppBarButton Label text. Text shows only when hamburger button is clicked and bar is expanded. How can I make text show along with the icon initially?

```
        CommandBar cb2 = new CommandBar();
        AppBarButton b3 = new AppBarButton();
        b3.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Help);
        b3.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        b3.Label = "HELP";

        cb2.PrimaryCommands.Add(b3);


        BottomAppBar = cb2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Command Bar has a property `IsOpen`. Set that to True. Then `CommandBar` is always open.

**Update**

```
<CommandBar IsOpen="True" Name="xCommand" IsSticky="True" IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add New Info"/>
</CommandBar>
```

This is my XAML. The command Bar Stays open at all times.

Comment: The moment I click any button, it shrinks again.

Comment: There is a AppBarClosedDisplayMode property and none of the values allow label to be shown.

Comment: Check Property IsSticky